# Groovy: Accessing class fields via list

Tags: list, groovy

First, I'm sorry for asking such a dumb question, but quick googling didn't help me much...

I'm a Java delevoper and very new to Groovy. Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Person {
    public String name
}

​def jack = new Person()
jack.name = "Jack"

​
def bob = new Person()
bob.name = "Bob"

def list = new java.util.ArrayList()

list.add(jack)
list.add(bob)

println list.name​
```

Executing it gives the following output (list of `name` field values for each `Person` in the list):

```
[Jack, Bob]
```

So my question is what the corresponding java code for calling `list.name`?
My assumption is that it translates to something like:

`list.stream().map(person -> person.name).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Can somebody explain what exactly happens when i call `list.name`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: nitpicking: you can just write `def list = [jack, bob]` in groovy, thanks to the list literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
list.property
```

is the shortest way to write this.  What groovy implies here is the use of the *spread operator*:

```
list*.property
```

(note the `*` there).  And `.property` *could* be short here for `.getProperty()`, for an implicit call to the getter).

So your assumption is correct, that this is the eager collection of the values `.getProperty()` returns into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is perfect!